# Flutter: Set volume by distance using vertical drag

Tags: flutter

I'm building a media player app. I'm trying to add swipe up or down vertical drag gesture to set volume like in vlc android player but can't achieve that accuracy. My code works but set volume with very short distance or whenever update function calls.

```
 onVerticalDragUpdate: (update) {
                    double position = update.primaryDelta;
                    if (position.isNegative) {
                        setVol(++currentVol);
                        updateVolumes();
                    } else {
                        setVol(--currentVol);
                        updateVolumes();
                    }
                  },
```

If anyone knows how to set volume with a distance limit like in mx player or vlc player. Please answer. My volume limit is (0-15).

Comment: `currentVol += update.primaryDelta * someFactor` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203612/discussion-between-hussnain-haidar-and-pskink).